# How to iterate through a list but stop at size-1

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, iterator

This code:

```
for (std::list<point>::const_iterator it = controlPoints->begin();
    it != controlPoints->end();
    ++it) {
    ...
    }
```

Corresponds to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < controlPoints->size; i++) {
...
}
```

Meaning, it would iterate through all elements of the list if I got one element for each time it looped.

What would correspond to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < controlPoints->size-1; i++) {
    ...
    }
```

I mean, how can I loop size-1 times using iterators?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The obvious way would be to get an iterator to the end and decrement it:

```
auto stop = controlPoints.end();
--stop;

for (std::list<point>::const_iterator it = controlPoints->begin();
    it != stop;
    ++it) {
    ...
    }
```

You could use `std::advance` or `std::next` if you preferred, but for this case a simple decrement is fine.

Comment: Just to explicitly state the pretty obvious caveat: make sure your `list<>` isn't empty beforehand as the `it != stop` condition won't work for that case (it's undefined behaviour).

Answer (score 6):

`controlPoints->end()` is also an iterator.

You could do this:

```
std::list<point>::const_iterator it = controlPoints->begin();
std::list<point>::const_iterator stop = controlPoints->end();
if ( it != stop) for ( --stop; it != stop; ++it) {
    ...
}
```

More verbose but it's safe to use whether the list has 0, 1 or more elements.

The key here is that iterators can be incremented and (for bidirectional iterators) decremented to advance / recede the position, so it's the equivalent of doing:

```
int it = 0;
int stop = list.size();
if (it != stop) for( --stop; it < stop; ++it ) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In C++11 you should seek to use the ranged based for loop as often as you can.  `for(;;)` loops are complex and error prone at the point you write them.

Using `for(:)` loops requires complexity away from the point you write them, but because you can write that infrastructure once and reuse it the bugs in it can be ironed out, instead of being dispursed throughout the code.

---

To start with, here is a simple `range_t`:

```
template<class It>
struct range_t {
  It b, e;
  It begin() const { return b; }
  It end() const { return e; }
  std::size_t size() const { return std::distance(begin(), end()); }
  using iterator_tag = typename std::iterator_traits<It>::iterator_category;
private:
  static It safe_advance( It in, It bound, std::ptrdiff_t n, std::random_access_iterator_tag ) const {
    if (n == 0) return in;
    if (n < 0) n = (std::min)( n, -std::distance( bound, in ) );
    if (n > 0) n = (std::max)( n, std::distance( in, bound ) );
    return std::advance( in, n );
  }
  static It safe_advance( It in, It bound, std::ptrdiff_t n, ... ) const {
    if (n == 0) return in;
    while (n < 0 && in != bound) {
      in = std::prev(in); --n;
    }
    while (n > 0 && in != bound) {
      in = std::next(in); ++n;
    }
    return in;
  }
public:
  range_t without_back( std::size_t n = 1 ) const {
    return {begin(), safe_advance( end(), begin(), -(std::ptrdiff_t)n, iterator_tag{} };
  }
  range_t without_front( std::size_t n = 1 ) const {
    return {begin(), safe_advance( end(), begin(), n, iterator_tag{} };
  }
  bool empty() const { return begin() == end(); }
  decltype(auto) front() const { return *begin(); }
  decltype(auto) back() const { return *std::prev(end()); }
};
template<class It>
range_t<It> range( It b, It e ) { return {b,e}; }
// rvalues blocked:
template<class C, class It = decltype( std::begin(std::declval<C&>()) )>
range_t<It> range( C& c ) { return range( std::begin(c), std::end(c) ); }
```

it stores a range of iterators and is itself iterable.

Then:

```
auto r = range(*controlPoints).without_back();
```

is a range object that is the `controlPoints` without the last element.

Using ranged-based for you can do this:

```
for (auto& x : range(*controlPoints).without_back()) {
}
```

note that the above code carefully handles being fed an empty array.

We can also write a similar adapter that lets you iterator over the iterators.  I usually do this by writing an `index_iterator` that stores an `Index` and passes `++` and `==` etc to it.  Except when you `*` it simply returns a copy of the `Index`.

This is useful to create an iterator over integers, but also lets you create an iterator over iterators.

Then create a range of indexes to the iterators in your container, and you get syntax that looks like:

```
for (auto it : iterators_into( *controlPoints) ) {
}
```

giving you range-based loops that also gives you iterators if you need them.